# Reason for .Net Com+TransactionProxyException and how to solve it?

Tags: .net, transactions, com+

I have a .Net 2.0 windows service using Com+ that imports xml data into a database, and most of the times it works perfectly fine.

However, sometimes (rarely) I get a transaction proxy exception thrown. (Happened once the last two months, 250 000 executions was correct during this time).

The worst part is, that data is imported to the database correctly, but the exception is thrown and the transaction is not rolled back. I've tried to manually create exceptions and verified that the transaction handling is correct.

Have you ever seen this before? There isn't much information about the error online. The service is running on a Server 2003 with SP2.

The exception thrown is:

> `System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionProxyException`

System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionProxyException
And the stacktrace:

> `System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionProxy.MapTxExceptionToHR(TransactionExceptiontxException, Boolean isInCommit)
>
>   at System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionProxy.Commit(Guid guid)
>
>   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>   at System.EnterpriseServices.Thunk.Callback.DoCallback(Object otp, IMessage msg, IntPtr ctx, Boolean fIsAutoDone, MemberInfo mb, Boolean bHasGit)
>   at System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponentProxy.CrossCtxInvoke(IMessage reqMsg)
>   at System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponentProxy.Invoke(IMessage request)
>
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>
>   at MyService`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing these DTC settings?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2556390

Comment: The database is on the same server as the service so I don't think its required. And if the Com+-settings is incorrect, shouldn't the service fail all the time then? (I will change the settings though, just to rule it out)